# How to use plot_model to represent the coefficient of an interaction between a quadratic variable and a dummy in R?

Tags: r, plot, interaction, multi-level, quadratic

I am trying to plot an interaction between a squared variable and a dummy from a multi-level logistic regression in R. Whilst I have no problem plotting these interactions with a non-quadratic variable, I have no idea about how to do it with interactions.

I can plot perfectly these interactions:

```
plot_model(model, type="eff", 
            pred.type = "re", 
            terms = c("first_variable[all]","dummy_variable"),  show.data = F,ci.lvl=.95)
```

But whenever I try to plot this

```
plot_model(model, type="eff", 
            pred.type = "re", 
            terms = c("I(first_variable^2)[all]","dummy_variable"),  show.data = F,ci.lvl=.95)
```

I always get this response:
`Error: Some of the specified` terms `were not found in the model. Maybe misspelled?`

I've tried spelling `first_variable^2`, `as.is(first_variable^2)`, but nothing seems to work. And it is a variable contained in my regression: `(glmer(y~first_variable+second_variable+I(first_variable^2)+I(first_variable^2):second_variable+(1|level2)+(1|level3), data = df3, family = binomial, nAGQ=1))`

Any idea on how can I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a comment about my self-made function for plotting non-linear effects, but I just learned that sjPlot can do it just fine now (it couldn't at the time I made it).

Your code is not working when you use `terms = c("I(first_variable^2)[all]")`

Just use `terms = c("first_variable[all]")` and you should get the output you need. Unless you're trying to isolate the interaction with the quadratic term without incorporating the linear component?

In the example below, I get a plot of the interaction with a quadratic term:

```
hdp <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hdp.csv")
m <- glmer(remission ~ Sex*RBC + Sex*I(RBC^2) +
             (1 | DID), data = hdp, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

sjPlot::plot_model(m, type="eff", pred.type = "re", terms = c("RBC[all]", "Sex"), show.data = F, ci.lvl = .95)
```

I also get the same output when I plot:

```
sjPlot::plot_model(m, type="pred", pred.type = "fe", terms = c("RBC[all]", "Sex"), show.data = F, ci.lvl = .95)
```